# jQuery "load" on webview

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use the jQuery `.load()` function on a `<webview/>` into a Chrome Packaged App.

This is my test did with an iFrame:

```
$('<iframe />').attr("src", "http://example.org").load(function(){
      $(this).addClass("shown");
}).appendTo('#body');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9ws5/1/

The problem is that when I try to use this code in my packaged app replacing `<iframe/>` with `<webview/>` it doesn't fire the `load` event.

I think the problem is that `webview` are different from `iframe`, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using the Chrome methods:

```
onload = function() {
  var webview = $("#webview");
  webview.on("loadstop", function () {
    webview.addClass("shown");
  });
}
```

(always read documentation! https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#methods)